# Force build on specific Docker layer

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile

I have a Docker file that downloads a tar file from some online git repo. The repo url stays the same but the content changes occasionally.

My Docker file builds regularly, and it can't detect the changes to that repo. Is there a way to force docker to always rebuild that specific layer? That layer is basically the following:

```
RUN curl --insecure -s https://gitlab.blahblah.com/something.tar -o /tmp/something.tar
```

I have considered various options, namely the `--no-cache`, which is kind of an overkill since I have multiple layers that actually benefit from the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the ADD layer.

```
ADD https://gitlab.blahblah.com/something.tar /tmp/something.tar
```

This layer is always executed when I run my builds.